# How to reset advertising id in iOS using hidden API?

Tags: ios

How can I reset the Advertising Identifier programmatically?

It can be manually done via `Setting` - `Privacy` - `Advertising` - `Reset Advertising Identifier`.

Comment: Formatting, language